# What happens to an ARC object that is CFBridgeRetained but only CFReleased?

Tags: ios, macos, memory, automatic-ref-counting, core-foundation

Assuming there are still outstanding strong references, does this result in a leak because nobody (neither ARC nor I) is managing the object anymore?

```
 CFTypeRef cf_object = CFBridgingRetain(arc_object);
 // do stuff
 CFRelease(cf_object);
```

Comment: Yes, if you use CF Retain, you need to use CFRelease.

Comment: Updated the code sample to clarify, sorry

Comment: OK, so it doesn't matter whether you call CFRelease or CFBridgingRelease?

Comment: @Rob, Yes you are correct. I didn't mean the release of `arc_object`. I was just stating the general rule. I should have read the question properly. This one looks fine now.

Comment: @Aaron, Please check this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/5773/beginning-arc-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-2

Comment: @Aaron "so it doesn't matter whether you call CFRelease or CFBridgingRelease?". No, you can either use `CFBridgingRelease` when you first set the value of the ARC object pointer and you can be confident that ARC will take care of it from that point on, or you call `CFRelease` of the core foundation object later when you're all done with the core foundation object. I think the former, `CFBridingRelease` is ideal, but you can do `CFRelease` manually if you really want.

Comment: By the way, the static analyzer ("Analyze" on the Xcode "Product" menu) is very good at diagnosing one's code for use of core foundation bridging and can diagnose many foundation leaks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question, the above code looks fine. You need to do a `CFRelease` when you are doing a CF `Create`, `Retain` or `Copy`. As Rob suggested you can also look into the usage of `CFBridgingRelease`.  For more details related to the ARC changes, you can look into this [Raywenderlich tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5773/beginning-arc-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-2).

As per [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFBridgingRetain) of `CFBridgingRetain`,

> Casts an Objective-C pointer to a Core Foundation pointer and also
>   transfers ownership to the caller.

```
CFTypeRef CFBridgingRetain(id X)
```

> **Discussion:**
>   You use this function to cast an Objective-C object as Core
>   Foundation-style object and take ownership of the object so that you
>   can manage its lifetime. You are responsible for subsequently
>   releasing the object.

Here you need to release the `cf_object` which ARC wont take care of it. Once you call `CFRelease`, it will be released.

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFBridgingRelease) on `CFBridgingRelease`

> Moves a non-Objective-C pointer to Objective-C and also transfers
>   ownership to ARC.

```
id CFBridgingRelease(CFTypeRef X)
```

> **Discussion:** You use this function to cast a Core Foundation-style object as an Objective-C object and transfer ownership of the object
>   to ARC such that you don’t have to release the object.

Note that when you use  `CFBridgingRelease`, it will transfer the ownership to ARC and ARC will manage it.

For eg:-

```
CFStringRef cfName = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
NSString *name = (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(cfName);
```

ARC will manage `name` here.

Answer (score 2):

In your revised question, the code you provided has no leaks. You casted an Objective-C object to a Core Foundation pointer, using `CFBridgingRetain`, increasing the core foundation object's retain count in the process. But, you balanced that with a `CFRelease`, which reduces the retain count back again (and when the retain count is zero, it will be deallocated), so all is good. No leaks.

Bottom line, this little Core Foundation round-trip to `cf_object` will not adversely affect ARC's management of the `arc_object`.

So, your question was:

> Assuming there are still outstanding strong references, does this result in a leak because nobody (neither ARC nor I) is managing the object anymore?

A couple of thoughts:

1. ARC never managed Core Foundation object `cf_object`. You are. And by calling `CFRelease`, you've fulfilled your responsibilities.
2. ARC never stopped managing the Objective-C object, `arc_object`. It still is. And when all strong references are removed (including any Core Foundation retain), the object will be deallocated.
3. You preface your question with a comment about there being other strong references. This is unrelated to the question of leaks, Core Foundation manual management of memory, etc. If your Core Foundation-related code code failed to clean up and caused a leak, it would do so, regardless of other strong references (though, admittedly, you generally don't actually experience/detect the leak until all other strong references are removed).

The question implies that you're concerned about leaks in your code and the use of Core Foundation objects and functions. The static analyzer ("Analyze" on Xcode's "Product" menu, or invoked by pressing <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>) is excellent at diagnosing your code for leaks, including your bridging and Core Foundation.

Comment: There is a build setting which tells Xcode to run the static analyzer on every build. I recommend turning that on. Better yet, use this: https://github.com/boredzo/warnings-xcconfig

Comment: @PeterHosey I'm always surprised how few people are familiar with the static analyzer. It's a wonderful, yet under appreciated, tool. Thanks for the feedback.